# Can I substitute parchment paper for foil?

Tags: baking

can I substitute parchment paper for the foil in a bar cookie recipe

Comment: Probably. Almost certainly. If you say exactly what you're making, i can say for sure.

Comment: @Stephie Presumably lining the pan to be able to lift the bars out after baking.

Answer (score 15):

Short answer for a short question: Probably. Assuming you're using it to line the pan, paper might leave the cookies less browned than you'd like, but it will provide a physical barrier between cookies and pan just fine. If you're using it to cover the bar cookies to keep them warm, foil works a lot better than paper. If you're cooking the cookies in a makeshift pan made solely out of foil by shoving the whole thing into a campfire, paper will definitely not work.

Comment: +1 for the image of making a pan out of paper and shoving it into a campfire.

Comment: an aptly cheeky response to a terminably(?) vague question!

Comment: but it would work for *boiling* in a campfire